# How to match a single file in nginx if there is a root location

Tags: nginx, single-page-application

I have a nginx config for single-page application with proxying app (it's json api) and static files (they're only loaded).

```
upstream my_app {
        server 127.0.0.1:3001;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location ~ ^/(api|admin|attachments|sitemap.xml)/ {
        proxy_pass http://my_app;
    }

    location / {
        alias /var/www/my_app/dist/;
        che, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0";
        try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
```

It successfully proxies queries for `api`, `admin`, `attachments` to `my_app`, but this doesn't happen with `sitemap.xml`. Nginx is trying to get `sitemap.xml` from `/var/www/my_app/dist`.

Why? How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'/sitemap.xml' doesn't match the regexp of your first location because it has a slash at the end. You can fix it in such a way:

```
location ~ ^/((api|admin|attachments)/|sitemap.xml$) {
    proxy_pass http://my_app;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, btw, I removed backslash for sitemap.xml